# Three consecutive powerful integers do not exist

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I (who is not a professional mathematician), ended up in the following on which I would like to have your comment, because this is overly simple solution. I know this certainly should not be easy and that is why I'm here.

*Powerful* numbers are defined as those $n$ which, for all primes, $p \mid n \implies p^2 \mid n$.

Two consecutive powerful numbers may be written as:

$$(A^2+n_1)(B^3+m_1)-A^2B^3=1 \tag{1}$$

Two powerful numbers a difference of which 2 may be written as:

$$(A^2+n_2)(B^3+m_2)-A^2B^3=2 \tag2$$

In both of these, $A, B, m_1, m_2, n_1, n_2$ are integers, and $A,B > 0$.

I suppose $A^2B^3,(A^2+n_1)(B^3+m_1),(A^2+n_2)(B^3+m_2)$ should then represent three consecutive powerful numbers.

Beckon$^1$ shows (as I understood):

> Three consecutive numbers are of one of the following forms: $(36k+7, 36k+8, 36k+9), (36k+27, 36k+28, 36k+29), \text{or } (36k-1, 36k, 36k+1)$.

We get from equation $(2): A^2m_2+B^3n_2+m_2n_2=2$, and after division by 2, we get

$$A^2M+B^3N=1-2MN \tag3$$

where $M=m_2/2$ and $N=n_2/2$.

Note that $m_2$ and $n_2$ must be even because $A$, $B$, $(A^2+n_2)$ and $(B^3+m_2)$ are odd. We can now formulate: **$M$ and $N$ do not have the same parity**.

We can notice that the following equations are constant:

$$\frac{(36k+7)(36k+9)+1}{(36k+8)^2}=1 \tag4$$

$$\frac{(36k+27)(36k+29)+1}{(36k+28)^2}=1 \tag5$$

$$\frac{(36k-1)(36k+1)+1}{(36k)^2}=1 \tag6$$

Examine now the equation $(4)$ of the three alternatives. We can replace the terms in the following manner: $36k+7=A^2B^3$ and $36k+9=(A^2+2N)(B^3+2M)$ in the equation $(4)$ which results in the following:

$$A^2B^2(A^2+2N)(B^3+2M)+1=16(9k+2)^2 \tag7$$

We can solve the equation $(7)$ for *M* and *N*:

$$
\begin{align}
M &=\frac{63-A^4B^6-2A^2B^6N+18(72k^2+32k)}{2A^2B^3(A^2+2N)} \implies \\
M &=\frac{\frac{63-A^4B^6}{2}-A^2B^6N+18(36k^2+16k)}{A^2B^3(A^2+2N)}
\end{align}
\tag8
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
N&=\frac{63-A^4B^6-2A^4B^3M+18(72k^2+32k)}{2A^2B^3(B^3+2M)} \implies \\ N&=\frac{\frac{63-A^4B^6}{2}-A^4B^3M+18(36k^2+16k)}{A^2B^3(B^3+2M)}
\end{align}
\tag9
$$

The equations $(8)$ and $(9)$ should be examined together. Based on the equation $(8)$, $M$ may or may not be divisible by two depending the term $\frac12(63-A^4B^6)$ and $N$. Because the same term is also in the equation $(9)$, $N$ is in the same situation. If the term $\frac12(63-A^4B^6)$ is divisible by two, the divisibility of *M* depends on *N* such that both must be divisible by two if one of them is divisible by two. If *M* is not divisible by two, it also means that *N* is not divisible by two. Both possibilities thus contradict the assumption that *M* and *N* do not have the same parity.

The two other cases $(5)$ and $(6)$ go in the same way (in order to keep this short I don't write them here). Note also that the condition $AB(A^2+2N)=0$ (denominator) is not possible because an even number cannot be an odd number (and $A$ and/or $B$ are/is not $0$).

What is above seems far too simple (Erdös could not solve this problem). OK, the question is, can this super tough problem be solved this easily? Or, can you point out where the calculations go wrong? Thank you for reading.

[1] *Beckon, Edward*, [**On consecutive triples of powerful numbers**](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/rhumj/vol20/iss2/3), Undergrad. Math J. 20, No. 2, Paper No. 3, 3 p. (2019). [ZBL1435.11010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1435.11010).

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: The problem should be really really tough. Erdös could not solve it. How come that it seems that easy? At least I don't know.

Comment: I think @Mike is asking what your question is.

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, I looked up what a powerful number is.  A positive integer $n$ is said to be powerful if, for every prime $p,$ if $p$ divides $n,$ then $p^2$ divides $n.$

Comment: Beckon is good and simple basis for this case. You can find it here: https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/rhumj/vol20/iss2/3/.

Comment: You haven’t sufficiently proven your initial assumption, i.e., that the number $$A^2B^3+1$$ has a factor larger than $A^2$ *and* a factor larger than $B^3$.

Comment: Could you, please, open your comment a little bit more, Kieren? How that kind of assumption or a lack of it could affect the final result?

Comment: Is the question whether there is a positive integer $n$, such that $n,n+1,n+2$ are all powerful ?

Comment: Three directly consecutive positive integers n, n+1, n+2 should be powerful numbers. That indeed is the point. It is not known if they exist or not. It is known that two consecutive powerful numbers exist, for example (8, 9); (9800, 9801) and (465124, 465125). The existence or non-existence of three consecutive powerful numbers has been a really hard problem. Please read Beckon and/or google.

Comment: All you're doing is looking at the equation(s) modulo $4$ and claiming a contradiction (which does not exist). The paper of Beckon you refer to just makes the (obvious) point that if $n-1, n, n+1$ are consecutive powerful numbers, then $n \equiv 0 \mod{4}$ and $n^3-n \equiv 0 \mod{9}$. In fairness, Beckon appears to be in grade 9....

Comment: Thank you, Mike Bennet.

Comment: After considering for a whlle I am afraid I did not fully understand your comment, Mike Bennet. The equations (4), (5) and (6) cause certain limitations (your comment relating to modulo 4). To me that seems unavoidable. Similarly unavoidable appears to be that M and N receive the same parity in the equations (8) and (9) although the equation (3) does not allow it. I would appreciate it a lot if you could explain a little bit more.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan $m_1, m_2, n_1, n_2$ can be negative. In fact, or each of $(1)$ and $(2)$, either the $m$ or the $n$ *must* be negative. The assumption you've written instead is impossible.

Comment: I *think* what you're asking here, @Tanaka, is: "I seem to have proven this conjecture. Since a solution evaded Erdös, and I'm not a professional mathematician, I am probably wrong! Please show me my error." Do I have that right?

Comment: You are right Eric Snyder. That is what I am asking. What I wrote is just absolutely too simple. I also think that *m* and *n* should have opposite signs (you can check the situation with a doublet, which do exist (a doublet must be included in a triplet)).

Comment: If there is a positive integer $n$ , such that $n,n+1,n+2$ are all powerful, then $n>10^{12}$. I would not be surprised, if a much better lower bound for $n$ is known.

Comment: If you want to be sure Mike Bennett (**not** Bennet) sees your comments, Tanaka, you have to put @MikeB in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alas, you haven't proven the conjecture. Your calculations go wrong in describing the parity implications of your equation $(8)$:

$$M =\frac{\frac{63-A^4B^6}{2}-A^2B^6N+18(36k^2+16k)}{A^2B^3(A^2+2N)} \tag8$$

Since we're only trying to pry things apart for parity, we can safely say that the denominator is odd (no matter the parity of $N$), the term containing $k$ is even, and $A^2B^6$ is odd. So we rewrite the equation as:

$$M = \frac{Q-ON+E}{O}$$

where $Q$ is the fractional term in the original, and the numbers of known parity are replaced with $O$ or $E$ as appropriate.

You claim that $2 \mid Q \implies (2 \mid M \iff 2 \mid N)$, which contradicts the previously proven $2 \mid M \iff 2 \nmid N$, and this claim is true so far as I can tell.

*However*, there's a second possibility: $2 \nmid Q$, i.e., $Q$ is odd. And this is where things go off course: you looked at the implications of $Q$ being even, but not of it being odd.

Assume $Q$ is odd. If $N$ is odd, then the numerator is even and thus $M$ is even. If $N$ is even, the numerator is odd, and $M$ must be odd. No contradiction here as long as $Q$ is odd--in fact, using both of those results, $2 \nmid Q \iff (2 \mid M \iff 2 \nmid N)$.

Sadly, what this means is you've proven that if a triple of this sort exists, and $A^2B^3 \equiv 7 \pmod{36}$, then $4 \nmid (63 - A^2B^3)$.

I'm guessing the opposite result (i.e. $Q$ must be even) may come from triples starting with numbers $n_1 \equiv 27 \pmod {36}$, since $27 \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ but $7, 35 \equiv 3 \pmod 8$. But I didn't do the math for the other cases because one counterexample suffices.

I hope this helps! Finding another person's miscalculation often proves an enlightening exercise.

Comment: I understand you mean $(63-A^2B^3)$ is not divisable by 4. If you write it $(64-(A^2B^3+1))$, it should be divisable by 4. Namely, Beckon teaches the middle number $(A^2B^3+1)$ is divisable by 4. The same should be true for the two other alternatives.

Comment: *Q* cannot be odd. Namely, $\frac{63-A^4B^6}{2}=\frac{64-(A^4B^6+1)}{2}$. Note $A^4B^6=(A^2B^3)^2$. When $\frac{A^2B^3+1}{4}=p$, where *p* is an integer, *Q* can be written $Q=\frac{64-(16p^2-8p+2)}{2}$. A corresponding result applies to the two other alternatives. This seems to become interesting.

Comment: Intriguing; you left that out of the logic in the OP, so I didn't notice. To shorten, setting $z=A^2B^3$, letting $P(x)$ mean "$x$ is powerful," and denoting the parity function as $p(x)$, then your full logic is:

(A) $P(z+1) \implies 4 \mid z+1$
(B) $4 \mid z+1 \implies p(M)=p(N)$
(C) $P(z) \land P(z+2) \implies p(M) \neq p(N)$
(D) $P(z) \land P(z+1) \land P(z+2) \implies p(M)=p(N) \land p(M) \neq p(N)$
(E) $\therefore \lnot (P(z) \land P(z+1) \land P(z+2))$

I'm not fully convinced, but I think it certainly merits a more thorough check.

Comment: Wait, wait; by your previous comment, $Q=32-8p^4p-1$, which is odd. But I see the issue; it's the squaring. $A^2B^3 = z \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ (as $4 \mid z +1$). That means $A^4B^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, so $A^4B^6 +1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$. That squaring makes a big difference; $Q$ will *always* be odd, never even. It might be more readily seen by using just $4k$ for the even number, rather than $36k+8$.

Comment: I don't know how the input box mangled $32-8p^2-4p-1$ so badly. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Thank you a lot for responding. I mixed things yesterday. I also found out *Q* is always odd. Note that $\frac{63-A^4B^6}{4}=p+\frac{1}{2}$, *p* is integer. From this $A^2B^3=\sqrt{61-4p}$. Also $\frac{A^2B^3+1}{4}=c$, *c* is integer. From this $A^2B^3=4c-1$. Then $\sqrt {61-4p}=4c-1$. The result is $p=-4c^2+2c+15$. Then $A^2B^3=\sqrt{16c^2-8c+1}=36k+7$. Now, *k* is: $k=\frac{c-2}{9}$. Inserting this to $A^2B^3=36k+7$ gives $A^2B^3=4c-1$ which has resemblance with Case 2 of Beckon. In any case, the problem seems to be in a loop somehow. Any idea to go ahead? Or is this the end?

Comment: @Tanaka It's hard to say for certain. There might be a further direction to branch off starting from this, but at some point you can't make much use of just substitution between various equations. Doing that will lead you into closed loops like the one you demonstrate in that last comment. But hey, recreational mathematics is just tinkering; perhaps you have something else you can use as a tool--or you need to learn another tool, which is also fun! Good luck.